# Is it possible to create a TypedDict equivalent with its own methods and properties in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, pytorch, python-typing, typeddict

I like to work with [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict)s to convey the batch and item information in PyTorch. It works well with the default collate function and adds the possibility to add types.

What I don't like is that you need to call it with strings keys, that is error prone, and that you can't define methods.

I usually overcome that by embedding the definition of the dicts as well as the keys and methods in a module. For example:

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class Keys:
    source = "source"
    encoding = "encoding"
    prediction = "prediction"

class Batch(TypedDict):
    source: list[str]
    encoding: Tensor  # Shape NCHV
    prediction: Tensor  # Shape N

class Item(TypedDict):
    source: str
    encoding: Tensor  # CHW
    result: float

def item_at(index: int, batch: Batch):
    """Extract an item from the batch"""
    return Item(...)

def get_source(x: Batch | Item):
    return x[Keys.source]

def set_source(x: Batch | Item, value: str | List[str]):
    x[Keys.source] = value
```

I think it could be more interesting to embed the methods into the `Batch` and `Item` classes.

However that's not allowed by `TypedDict`. On the other hand, when I inherit from `dict`, I don't know how to add the types.

Do you know how to to do the trick and have a `TypedDict` equivalent with its own methods and properties?

Comment: `TypedDict` is basically a special-cased construct that allows you to use dict's with structural typing, you cannot really create it, at least not in a way that works with python's type system as defined by PEP 484

Comment: "What I don't like is that you need to call it with strings keys, that is error prone, and that you can't define methods." I don't get it, why don't you just define *a class*? Why are you working with a `TypedDict` at all if you *don't want a dict*?

Comment: Please put a little bit more effort into your questions. There were loads of errors and formatting issues in your code. And you are referencing some unknown `Tensor` type. If you want people to be able to reproduce your errors/problems, at least test your code example once before posting it.